# how to create super admin in my phpMyAdmin?

Tags: asp.net, sql, mysql, phpmyadmin

I just finished my website here I used ASP.net & MySQL.

I uploaded my website file all right.

But the problem is with my database.  I create my database very will and I create all my tables but the problem is that I can't execute my stored procedure?

That is because i don't have the privileges to do this operation?
The error in phpMyAdmin is:

MySQL said:

```
#1227 - Access denied; you need the SUPER privilege for this operation
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As MySQL root:

```
$ mysql -u root -p     # ..or, if no password has been set..
$ mysql -u root
```

Run this command:

```
GRANT SUPER ON *.* TO user@localhost;
```

Further reading:

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/grant.html

Comment: MySQL said: 

#1045 - Access denied for user 'Hero'@'%' (using password: YES)

Comment: @HAJJAJ: You don't have the necessary privileges to grant this right, then; ask someone who has them (your DBA, your hosting provider - who this is depends on your exact situation).

Comment: ask who ?

i am the only one who create this account and make username and password!!

Comment: yes you was right , i contact my website server an they solve the problem.